# How to check PREROUTING list from iptable in linux?

Tags: linux, iptables

I added packet forwarding rule in my iptable
`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.126:80`
and I can see that the packet coming to port 1111 is correctly forwarded to 10.0.3.126:80. However if I list up the rules, I cannot see the rule that I added.

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

How can I view the rule I added?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: sudo iptables-save

Comment: Thanks @MichaelO.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use `iptables -L -n -t nat` command
 Because PREROUTING chain is a part of NAT rules

Comment: Isn't it also part of mangle ? So wouldn't you have to look at the PREROUTING chain for mangle and nat? Or are the chains not table specific?

Comment: PREROUTING is a phase, NAT is table, the relation is PREROUTING has a NAT table of chains, and chain has rules. The reason you need to add `-t nat` is `As every other iptables command, it applies to the specified table (filter is the default)`, refer to https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables